# Bitcoin service regulations

Tags: canada, regulations, cryptocurrency, currency, money-service

Most governments don't consider Bitcoin to be currency, so it's somewhat of a legal gray zone regarding regulation.  I know most exchanges must follow KYC/AML systems because they trade with fiat too, but for services which only exchange cryptocurrency, is there any regulation?

For example, Bitcoin gambling sites or mixers don't follow regulation, do they?

Comment: Probably best to limit the scope of "is there any regulation?" to a specific country or jurisdiction, otherwise you'll probably not get an answer (or ones that you don't want).

Comment: Let's say Canadian law specifically?

Comment: What is considered "currency" by law depends on the scope and context of the law. You can't generally take a definition from one area of law and apply it in another. Gambling laws have been taken to cover valuable e-property (e.g. "loot boxes"), so they probably cover Bitcoins as well.